# Seam - Redirect last visited page after logout/login

Tags: redirect, jboss7.x, seam3

I am working with seam 3 and I am trying to get the user back to the last page he visited. Like when I restart my server, the session is cleared and I am logged out. Now when I log back in I would like to get back directly to the page I was on before restarting the server, and not on the homepage.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the currently viewed page to a persistent store (eg. database) against the current user